# How to set rel="alternate" hreflang="x"?

Tags: 7, i18n-l10n

I am trying to set my hreflang links with this code:

```
$langcode= $GLOBALS['language']-> language;
//Get enabled languages
$langcode= array_pop(language_list('enabled'));
unset ($languages[$langcode->language]);

// Get path
$path1 = drupal_is_front_page() ? '<front>' : $_GET['q'];
//Get Urls 
$links = array();
foreach ($languages as $lang) {
  $links[$lang->language] = array(
    'href'=> $path1,
    'language'=>lang,
    'absolute'=> TRUE,
  );
}
drupal_alter('translation_link', $links, $path1);

//Set head tags
foreach($links as $link) {
  drupal_set_html_head('<link rel="alternate" hreflang="'.   $link['language']->language .'" href="'. url($link['href'], $link) .'" />');
}
//Update head
$vars['head'] = drupal_get_html_head();
```

with no luck.

While researching I have found this module [Internationalization contributions](http://drupal.org/project/i18n_contrib)
but it doesn't do anything. Or I don't know how to use it.

Comment: What part of the code doesn't do what you want? You can't just dump code and say "It doesn't work". Where is this code? Have you even checked it's actually running? If what Clive says is true, this code should give a fatal error.

Comment: I am using this code inside my  function mytheme_preprocess_page in the template.php file. No fatal error at all. Where i can see at least.

Answer (score 2):

You tagged your question as Drupal 7 so I'm guessing the only problem is that you're using `drupal_set_html_head()` which doesn't exist in Drupal 7.

It's been replaced with [`drupal_add_html_head()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21common.inc/function/drupal_add_html_head/7), which you can use like so:

```
$element = array(
  '#tag' => 'link', 
  '#attributes' => array( 
    'hreflang' => 'some_language', 
    'rel' => 'alternate',
  ),
);
drupal_add_html_head($element, 'mymodule');
```

Comment: So i have to create it as a module to be able to include it? What about the module i have already mentioned? Are you familiar with this?

Comment: It should work fine in a theme as well, the 'mymodule' bit is just a key to be able to identify the tag; 'mytheme' would work just as well, as would 'my_pet_dog' or any other string. I haven't used the contributions module before so I can't help with that I'm afraid

Comment: so is the path! Ok i see! So if i understand correctly it should be something like this?

Comment: // Get path
 $path1 = drupal_is_front_page() ? '<front>' : $_GET['q'];
 //Get Urls 
 $links = array();
 foreach ($languages as $lang) {
   $links[$lang->language] = array(
     '#tag'=> 'link',
     'hreflang'=>lang,
     'rel'=> 'alternate',
   );
}
drupal_alter('translation_link', $links, $path1);

//Set head tags
foreach($links as $link) {
  drupal_set_html_head('<link rel="alternate" hreflang="'.   $link['language']->language .'" href="'. url($link['href'], $link) .'" />');
}
//Update head
$vars['head'] = drupal_add_html_head();

Comment: I'm not sure if you need to set `$vars['head']` (definitely not if your code is in `hook_preprocess_page` and not `hook_preprocess_html`). Best thing to do would be to test it out and see if you run into any problems

Comment: I did tested it with no luck. Yes the code is in the mytheme_preprocess_page function. But if i remove the drupal_set_html_head(...) how the array will iterate and generate results?

Comment: I put my code in the mytheme_preprocess_html function with no luck. Is my code ok now? Look below

Comment: $langcode= array_pop(language_list('enabled'));
unset ($languages[$langcode->language]);
$path1 = drupal_is_front_page() ? '<front>' :$_GET['q'];
 //Get Urls 
 $links = array();
 foreach ($languages as $lang) {
   $links[$lang->language] = array(
     '#tag'=> 'link',
     'hreflang'=>lang,
     'rel'=> 'alternate',
   );
     }
     drupal_alter('translation_link', $links, $path1);
   foreach($links as $link) {
    drupal_set_html_head('<link rel="alternate" hreflang="'.   $link['language']->language .'" href="'. url($link['href'], $link) .'" />');
}
   $vars['head'] = drupal_add_html_head();

Answer (score 2):

Just use the mentioned module http://drupal.org/project/i18n_contrib and enable the sub-module **i18n_hreflang**, this will provide the hreflang in the head section of your website automatically across your translated pages. **(clear cache!)**
Use the latest state (dev-release) to have some improvements already in.
Sure I will create soon an new stable release too.

Answer (score 2):

Another option for adding the hreflang tag is this module: [Alternate hreflang](https://www.drupal.org/project/hreflang)

> Alternate hreflang is a simple module that automatically adds these tags to your pages. It has no dependencies, but works well with [Entity Translation](https://www.drupal.org/project/entity_translation).